# Set a locale in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, date, internationalization, locale

jQuery tests the validity of a date via:

```
!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))
```

`new Date(dateString)` is the same as `Date.parse(dateString)` and uses browser/OS locale to parse the string.

I'm trying to parse `DD/MM/YYYY` but I get an error because my browser is looking for `MM/DD/YYYY`. Since my product will be used only by `DD/MM` people, I want to force this behaviour.

I could write a custom validator, but is it possible to change the browser locale via JavaScript as well?

Comment: "*…and uses browser/OS locale to parse the string*". No it doesn't.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

You can't change the locale, as there is no such feature in the EMCAScript [specification](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php).

However, there is a nice package called [php.js](http://phpjs.org/) that implements PHP functions in JavaScript.

Two of the functions are [setlocale](http://phpjs.org/functions/setlocale:589)() and [date](http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380)(). You can use them.

Comment: Wow, I would never ever recommend that anybody touch that php.js code with a pole of arbitrary length. Yuk.

Comment: He can always watch the dependencies and use only the necessary functions.

Comment: im not using the php.js, accepted for the information that its impossible to change locale in javascript

Comment: Wow. Suggesting, not only that he utilize a huge library for this single purpose… but suggesting, specifically, a library that emulates *PHP*‽ That’s… irresponsible, to say the least. -1’d.

Comment: Well, if you have any other idea, you are welcome to post it. Otherwise, he can use the *specified functions* from php.js. No need to use the whole library of course.

Comment: "impossible" *proceeds to link to javascript library stating it is possible*

Comment: Browser/OS language is irrelevant in regard to how *Date.parse* deciphers timestamps.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use JavaScript's Internationalization API because it's now supported in all browsers.  It allows you to pass in a locale, which will customize the date format.

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP asked. They want to know how to parse a timestamp based on a specific language ("locale"), not produce a timestamp based on language.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse dates.

```
//parse string according to format and return new moment
var day = moment("16/12/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY");  

var dayAsDate = day.toDate();  //you can even covert the moment to a Date
```

[Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) also has a [date parsing module](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-parser.md) if you need to handle date strings in other locales/scripts.

---

For everyone else who arrived here from Google, you can't change the browser or Javascript locale from JS, but you can use:

- JS/browser built-in [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to *format* dates (but not parse them) - it's unclear how many locales and scripts this supports, and it may depend on the browser
- The lib [Globalize.js](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize), initially coded by Microsoft, which supports full CLDR data, to parse or format numbers
- Use the lib [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to format and parse dates according to a format you specify (but no locale-specific formats)

Answer (score -3):

If your product will only be used by DD/MM/YYYY people, set your browser to a DD/MM/YYYY supporting locale.