# get date format by locale code javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, locale, date-format

I was wondering whether there is a special function to be used in javascript to get a dateFormat by locale code.

```
String dateFmt = function_get_date_format_by_locale_code ('en');
```

would return MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: In what browser do you have formatting possibilities on the toString() without changing the prototype?

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385474/set-a-locale-in-javascript

Comment: I found something similar, which may spurt more thoughts to add to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673905/best-way-to-determine-users-locale-within-browser

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to the question, but you could try using [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), a great little library for working with dates in JavaScript. It has some locale functionality/support I believe...